# Use Parquet UUID LogicalType in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am using pyspark and I want to read/write parquet data with uuids in it, which I'd prefer to save as the parquet UUID LogicalType (which is a 16-bytes fixed array).

See https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md

How can I do so in pyspark?

I was wondering whether I should try to extend `class pyspark.sql.types.DataType` and translate between `bytes` and `uuid.UUID`, however it is not clear to me how spark would then write that as the UUID logical type in parquet.

Comment: why don't you just save as binary type?

Comment: I'd like to deal with them as UUIDs, what they are. This is helpful in debugging, or just about anywhere where humans interact with the data. So maybe I'm a bit unclear in the question: I do want the UUID logical type to be used as I wouldn't know how to communicate to spark otherwise that the binary is actually a UUID. In turn I want the code to deal with `uuid.UUID` and vice versa I want `uuid.UUID` to be stored as the binary.

Comment: Hi. Any luck on this? I am facing the same issue and I can't find any docs about it

Comment: @ArthurPassos unfortunately not. It's a pitty. We shifted our stack to python/dask meanwhile, but it also doesn't have great support for it. PyArrow for instance doesn't support the LogicalType either, so none of our tools have it (Presto, Spark, Pandas), although the underlying languages (Java, Python) have decent support for it (`java.lang.UUID`, `uuid.UUID`) in their standard libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I am stuck on this for a couple of days already. I did see some mentions of Java code, but I couldn't find any useful example. Have you ever done such thing in Java?